# Can't display intiali value in JoptionPane within JDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

This is probably a dumb question, but I can't figure out how to fix it.  I want all my JoptionPanes to be resizable, so I am imbedding them in JDialog. I will have to convert all my showXxxDialog calls eventually, so I decided to start with showInputDialog.  Everything works (the Dialog looks nice, and is resizable), except that it won't display the initial value in the JOptionPane display, even though it is correct in the JOptionPane constructor.  Here is my code (messageType is PLAIN_MESSAGE, but QUESTION_MESSAGE does the same):

```
public class MyOptionPane {

static Object showInputDialog(Object f,  Object message, String title, int messageType, 
      Icon ico, Object[] options, Object initValue) {

     JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, messageType, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
         ico, options,  initValue);

     JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog((Component) f, title);
     if (!dialog.isResizable()) {
         dialog.setResizable(true);
     }
     pane.setWantsInput(true);

     dialog.pack();              
     dialog.setVisible(true);           

     return pane.getInputValue();   

     }
 }
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please show us an example of how you call this. Also, are you sure that the initial value is part of the options array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good and bad news, a fix to your problem is to include the line: `pane.setInitialSelectionValue(initValue);`. Great right? Well the bad news is that I cannot explain why it doesn't auto insert the initValue via the constructor. Hopefully someone else can build off of this and explain to us both.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyOptionPane {

    static Object showInputDialog(Object f,  Object message, String title, int messageType,
                                  Icon ico, Object[] options, Object initValue) {


        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, messageType, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                ico, options,  initValue);

        JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog((Component) f, title);
        if (!dialog.isResizable()) {
            dialog.setResizable(true);
        }
        pane.setInitialSelectionValue(pane.getInitialValue()); // set it
        pane.setWantsInput(true);

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        return pane.getInputValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: @PaulMorrison, doesn't work for me. Well, yes I do see a value in the input field. However, the above code only works when you specify null for the "options" variable. When you provide an array of options you should have a combo box displayed for the input component, but I get multiple buttons with the array values. So I would still suggest something is wrong. Then again maybe my test code is wrong, that is why you were asked to post your SSCCE demonstrating the problem. The context of how the method is used is also important.

Comment: Thanks, camickr, options is null - calling code: String ans = (String) MyOptionPane.showInputDialog(driver.frame,        "Enter or change text", "Edit upstream port name",
     JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, upStreamPort);

Comment: @PaulMorrison, The entire test code should be posted with your question so that we can copy/paste/compile and test. I suggested that the code here will work in that case, however, that is NOT how that method from the JOptionPane is intended to be used all the time. It is intended to be used to provide a list of options for the user to choose from. Check out [Getting the User's Input from a Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input). I am suggesting this code will no longer support this default functionality.

Comment: Possibly it's not working because: "initialValue: the choice that is initially selected; if null, then nothing will be initially selected; **only meaningful if options is used**" as per `JOptionPane` Javadoc

Comment: Thanks, @camickr, that was the only way I could see to insert an initial value.  There's probably a correct way - I'll do some more digging!  The real problem is that IMHO the documentation for JOptionPane is terrible!  The basic showxxxDialog functions are pretty good, but the moment you want to do something non-standard, you get no help at all.  Presumably the constructors somehow tie in with the showxxxDialog functions, but it's extremely difficult to figure out how! Still, I think I am making progress - with the help of all of you! Thanks! :-)

Comment: @PaulMorrison, `that was the only way I could see to insert an initial value.` the API has other methods that are designed to display a simple text field for input and allow you to specify the initial. Anyway, you've been given an answer, so you should be accepting the answer.

Comment: @camickr I looked at <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input">Getting the User's Input from a Dialog</a> and it specifically says to set options to null in my case.  For the case where options are needed (one case in my app), I won't bother with resizing.  Thanks anyway!